# Adding colors in csv file in shell script

Tags: linux, shell, unix

I have created a csv file which has two contents pasted one beside the other,At the bottom the differences between those two files are printed using diff,It is possible to print those differences in red color in csv and below headings in bold using shell script.

source(bold)               target(bold)

differences(red color)

Tried the below,but it didnt work:
RED='\033[0;31m'
printf " ${RED}DIFFERENCES\n"

Comment: CSV files don't have colours - they are plain, unadorned text files used for reliably and simply exchanging tabular data between applications/systems.

Comment: Is it possible in excel?

Comment: You can colour cells in Excel but then you will get an XLSX file - but that is no longer a nice, clean CSV data-interchange format that doesn't require proprietary, paid-for software. What are you trying to do - exchange data or make a pretty, coloured output? What is important to you?

Comment: If the CSV file at the bottom contains something in diff format, it is no longer a CSV file.

Comment: You should consider that the actual data and the visualization of the data are two very separate things. One should not confuse both. So leave the data alone and create a visualization layer. But whatever means you like. _That_ is where you want to add your color.

Comment: @MarkSetchell My priority is data present in csv and adding color is secondary.